# Getting the length of a list using combinators f#

Tags: f#, combinators

```
let length (l : 'a list) =
  let mutable counter = 0
  for i in l do
    counter <- counter + 1
  counter

let list1 = [ 10; 25; 34; 45; 78 ]
length list1
```

I can get the length of a list using the above piece of code (in F#) but I'm wondering how I can do this exact code using combinators. If anyone could help out that'd be great, thanks!

Comment: higher order functions using the "fun" keyword. let checkFor item =
    let functionToReturn = fun lst ->
                           List.exists (fun a -> a = item) lst
    functionToReturn

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned by Vidas, you can just use the built-in `List.length` function, which is the best way to do this in practice. However, if you are interested in more options, then the basic alternative is to use recursion:

```
let rec length l = 
  match l with 
  | [] -> 0
  | x::xs -> 1 + (length xs)
```

This is not written using combinators, but it's a basic functional pattern. The general pattern of the function is captured by the `fold` function, which lets you (basically) specify the two branches of the pattern matching. Using `fold` you can write:

```
let list1 = [ 10; 25; 34; 45; 78 ]
List.fold (fun s x -> s + 1) 0 list1
```

This says that the initial state is `0` and, for every element, we increment the state `s` by `1` - so the result will be the length of the list.

If you wanted to do something completely crazy, you could try to replace the function `fun s x -> s + 1` with a function composed using combinators. This will make your code unreadable (and nobody should ever do this), but it's fun to think how to do this. You might need a helper function that takes a function, two arguments and passes the two arguments to the function as a tuple:

```
let tuple f = fun a b -> f (a, b)
```

Now you can write something like the code below - which is as using as much combinator style as possible, but it's pretty hard to decipher.

```
List.fold (tuple (fst >> (+) 1)) 0 list1
```

So, `List.length` is the way to go :-).

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are asking for

```
Seq.length list1
```

Comment: This is a built in function, I think he's asking for something similar to J doe's comment on the main question, i.e (fun x -> x ....etc)